# Button shows in preview but not in the build

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a button in my second activity that shows in the activity_2.xml preview but when i run the app and switch to the second activity, the button is gone. Not just graphically. I can't either see or click on the button. Everything else works fine.

I'm using Android Studio 2022.3.1 and kotlin. All of the activities I'm using were 'empty activity'.

**activity_main.xml**
[image: activity_main.xml]

**activity_2.xml**
[image: activity_2.xml]

*MainActivity.kt*

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    var btGoto: Button? = null
    var etText: EditText? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btGoto = findViewById(R.id.bt_goTo)
        etText = findViewById(R.id.et_text)
        listener()
    }

    private fun listener() {
        btGoto?.setOnClickListener {

            if (etText!!.length() < 1)
                Toast.makeText(this, "This field can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            else{
                val goToA2Intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
                goToA2Intent.putExtra("text", etText!!.text.toString())
                startActivity(goToA2Intent)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

*Activity2.kt*

```kotlin
class Activity2 : ComponentActivity() {

    var text: String? = ""
    var tvText: TextView? = null
    var btBack: Button? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2)

        btBack = findViewById(R.id.bt_back)
        tvText = findViewById(R.id.tv_text)
        text = intent.getStringExtra("text").toString()
        tvText?.setText(text)
        listener()
    }

    private fun listener(){
        btBack?.setOnClickListener{
            var backToMainAIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(backToMainAIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

I can't think of any solution so i came here looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason why this bug happens.
Since the button width is set to "wrap_content", the button's width will be as wide as it needs to be and since its position is linked to the TextView above it and the TextView's text changes by what you enter in the EditText field from the previews activity, we can say *IF YOU ENTER A TEXT THAT'S TOO SHORT, THE BUTTON CAN'T BE SHOWN BECAUSE IT DOESN'T HAVE THE ENOUGH WIDTH.*

Now the simple solution to this is to replace the

```
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_text"
```

with

```
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

in the *activity_2.xml* file so the button will still be at the center but not linked to the TextView anymore.